# windows not getting IP address from Raspberry pi access point

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

I have looked at several posts but they don't seem to match my situation 100%

I have a Raspberry Pi 4b, 2g. I installed Bullseye 32 bit desktop (the default in Raspberry pi imager). Did all the updates, downloaded hostapd and dnsmasq. set the configurations.

Windows can see and can connect to the wireless network however when I try and do an ipconfig I get back an address of 192.168.137.1. The address range my DHCP server is set for is 192.168.42.100 - 192.168.42.200.

I can connect and get an ipaddress and even ssh into the pi from a linux box just fine.

Why is windows not playing well with the pi other than the fact that it's windows?

Comment: I don't understand. When your Windows has  192.168.137.1, it can connect to the Pi. Is that on the same subnet or via a router? Is that wired or via WiFi? What is/are the addresses of the Pi? Can you add `dhcpd.conf` and the output of `ifconfig -a` on the Pi and `ipconfig` on Windows to the question?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Even though this was a brand new usb wireless adapter windows in its infinite wisdom some how decided to create a static ip profile for it. I reset it to use DHCP and its working now.